# PyQt4 Python Gui Coding: Request for help debugging syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I am learning PyQt4 and have written a simple expression evaluator.  I am having difficulty debugging the second to last line of my **init** function (self.connect..... ).  Python returns 'syntax error' but I can't spot the problem.  I'd appreciate any help you can offer pointing it out.  I am using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 13.10 Linux 64 bit.  I am aware that the whitespace formatting is slightly off which is an artifact of my cutting and pasting but the code IS EXACTLY as I am running it otherwise.

```
<pre> <code>
from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Form, self).__init__(tparent)
    self.browser = QTextBrowser()
    self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an epression and press enter")
    self.lineedit.selectAll()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.browser)
    layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.lineedit(self.setFocus()
    self.connect(self.lineedit,  SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),self.updateUi)
    self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")

def updateUI(self):
    try:
        text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
        self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s</b>" % (text, eval(text)))
    except:
        self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is invalid!</font>" % text)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close paren from the line above

```
self.lineedit(self.setFocus())
self.connect(self.lineedit,  SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),self.updateUi)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! LOL!  It's the silly stuff always gets me!  "Slow down speedy Gonzalez!" my gradeschool math teacher used to always yell at me.  Guess she was right.  Muchos Gracias, Senior Rawrgulmuffins!

Comment: @user2966876: What IDE are you using? You should use something with syntax highlighting that will tell you where your errors are.